# Lucene not working when search with multiples words phrase

Tags: java, solr, lucene

i have this index with Lucene:

```
  Document document = new Document();
  document.add(new TextField("termos", text, Field.Store.YES));
  document.add(new TextField("docNumber",fileNumber,Field.Store.YES));

  config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
  Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer("standard")
                .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
                .addTokenFilter("stop")
                .addTokenFilter("porterstem")
                .addTokenFilter("capitalization")
                .build();
  config = IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
  writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config);
  writer.addDocument(document);
  writer.commit();
```

After this, i made some searchs, and for just one word it looks fine. The problems is when the search have a lot of words:

```
    Query query = new QueryBuilder(analyzer).createPhraseQuery("termos","THE_PHRASE");
    String indexDir = rootProjectFolder + "/indexDir/";
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(1000,1000);
    searcher.search(query,collector);
```

Im always getting 0 results in phrases. Look that im using the same analyzer type for index and search, and i have to tokenizer to index.

Im new in Lucene. What is wrong?